# Move row up and down in knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

Hi all I have a requirement like I would like to move row up and down when I click on corresponding row, but when there is a text box present on top I want to show the row as it is else it should get moved, similarly when there is a text box present at the bottom or if it is the last row I would like to show the row as it is if not I should move it to below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var knockoutModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        var jsonData = [{
            "groupname": "group1",
            "groupData": [{
                "Name": "XYZ",

            }, {
                "Name": "ABC",
            }, ]

        }, {
            "groupname": "group2",
            "groupData": [{
                "Name": "XYZ",
            }, {
                "Name": "DEF",
            }]

        }];

        this.myData = ko.observableArray(jsonData);
        this.moveUp = function (data) {

            var idx = self.myData.indexOf(data),
              tmp = self.myData.splice(idx, 1);

            self.myData.splice(idx - 1, 0, tmp[0]);
        };
        this.moveDown = function (data) {
            var idx = self.myData.indexOf(data),
              tmp = self.myData.splice(idx, 1);

            self.myData.splice(idx + 1, 0, tmp[0]);
        };
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new knockoutModel());
```

Here is what I tried but couldn't get as per required https://jsfiddle.net/JSFiddler1/bkv12nh2/

Comment: Can you describe your problem a little more?
Also, you can do: `<button data-bind="click: $root.moveUp">Up</button>` instead of having a `function` in there.

Comment: You're moving groups instead of individual rows. The rows are inside the groups.